# How to convert date/time in seconds to date/time we can read?

Tags: date, dax

In my database I've got a field like: `1434471505`

This means: `2015/06/16 12:18:25`

This is because the database is MySQL and it uses PHP date/time measured in seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

So, the following script returns the date above:

```
<?php
$numberofsecs = 1434471505;
echo date('Y/m/d H:i:s', $numberofsecs);

?>
```

I need a similar function for DAX, like `DATE`. But, which function?

Tried to calculate the number of years, months, days, minutes and seconds since 1-1-1970 00:00 but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can't understand your DAX. Its syntax is completely wrong.

Comment: @AlexBlex It looks like this is asking how to do it in DAX rather than MySQL.

Comment: I would use this for your dates and times https://momentjs.com/

Comment: If you want to convert from Unix timestamp to string in DAX just ask so. Your tags and remarks about MySQL and PHP only add confusion (MySQL doesn't even use timestamps by default).

Comment: I've removed the PHP tag, now my question only has DAX and DATE tags

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
Date_readable = VAR UnixDays = 'table'[dateinsecs]/(60*60*24)
RETURN (DATEVALUE("1/1/1970")+UnixDays)
```

Thanks everyone for helping.